# Traces on Polynomial Regression

Tags: python, pandas, graph, regression

Hello I'm having troube trying to predict the Weekly Sales based on the fuel price using polynomial regression. I saw someone else ask the same question and tried the only answer but I still can't get a good graph. Here's what I've done:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stderr
from turtle import color, pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

df = pd.read_csv (r'Walmart.csv')
df = df.sort_values(by=['Weekly_Sales'])

y = df.loc[:, "Fuel_Price"].sample(n = 50, random_state= 6)
x = df.loc[:, "Weekly_Sales"].sample(n = 50, random_state= 6)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)

X_poly = poly.fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1,1))
poly.fit(X_poly,y)
linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X_poly,y)
y_pred = linreg.predict(X_poly)
plt.scatter(x, y, color='red')
plt.plot(x,y_pred, color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

Result:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hpyz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that `x` are not in order after randomly sampling them from `df`. Replace the x and y sampling lines lines with

```
...
xy = df.sample(n = 50, random_state= 6).sort_values(by=['Weekly_Sales']) 
y = df["Fuel_Price"]
x = df["Weekly_Sales"]
...
```

and it should work. Eg for some made up data:

[image]

Alternatively you can plot the blue line as a scatter and it would not matter if the `x`s are not in order

```
...
plt.plot(x,y_pred ,'.', color = 'blue')
...
```

and it would look like this:

[image]